# 2 sets of radio button php my sql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am making a survey system for my college project. But I'm having a hard time with radio buttons. I successfully made 1 set of radio button and it values is being sent to my database. But when I make two sets of radio button, only the first set of radio button is being sent to my database. can someone help me?

```
if (isset($_GET['Submit1']) && isset($_GET['q']) && isset($_GET['q1'])) {

    $selected_radio = $_GET['q'];
    $selected_radio2 = $_GET['q1'];



    $idNumber = $_GET['h1'];



$user_name = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "survey";
$server = "127.0.0.1";

$db_found = new mysqli($server,$user_name, $password, $database );

    if ($db_found) {

        if($selected_radio == "A") {
            $votedSQL = "UPDATE tblsurvey SET VotedA = VotedA + 1 WHERE ID = ?";
            $voteMessage = insert_vote($db_found, $votedSQL, $idNumber);
        }
        else if($selected_radio == "B"){
            $votedSQL = "UPDATE tblsurvey SET VotedB = VotedB + 1 WHERE ID = ?";
            $voteMessage = insert_vote($db_found, $votedSQL, $idNumber);
        }
        else if($selected_radio == "C"){
            $votedSQL = "UPDATE tblsurvey SET VotedC = VotedC + 1 WHERE ID = ?";
            $voteMessage = insert_vote($db_found, $votedSQL, $idNumber);
        }
        else if($selected_radio2 == "D") {
            $votedSQL = "UPDATE tblsurvey SET VotedD = VotedD + 1 WHERE ID = ?";
            $voteMessage = insert_vote($db_found, $votedSQL, $idNumber);
        }
        else if($selected_radio2 == "E"){
            $votedSQL = "UPDATE tblsurvey SET VotedE = VotedE + 1 WHERE ID = ?";
            $voteMessage = insert_vote($db_found, $votedSQL, $idNumber);
        }
        else if($selected_radio2 == "F"){
            $votedSQL = "UPDATE tblsurvey SET VotedF = VotedF + 1 WHERE ID = ?";
            $voteMessage = insert_vote($db_found, $votedSQL, $idNumber);
        }
        else {
            print "Error - could not record vote";
        }   
    }
}

else {
    print "You didn't select a voting option!";
```

Comment: post code and not pictures

Comment: pictures may be removed from the link you have provided, so as suggested post complete code and where you are getting problems.

Comment: Use another variable for the 2nd set of radio value as of now you are using the same variable to check for all 6 values from A to F

Answer (score 0):

try diff name for diff group

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="group12"> group12<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="group123"> group123<br>

<input type="radio" name="group2" value="group2"> group2<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="group23"> group23
```